# Drawing circles in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a problem to create circle whenever I like to call the paint function it will draw me another circle. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyOnto extends JFrame
{
    int weight = 960;
    int heigh = 960;
    int x  = 200;
    int y = 100;

    //Graphics p;

    private static MyOnto my = new MyOnto();

    public MyOnto()
    {
            setTitle("My Ontology");
            setSize(weight, heigh);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            drawing(g,x,y,100,50);  //g, x ,y, w, h of circle
    }

    public void drawing(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
            g.drawOval(x,y,w,h);
            g.drawString("Helo", x+25,y+20);
            x = x + 100;
            y = y + 100;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            //my = new MyOnto();
            my.paint(null);
            my.paint(null); //try to print one more circle
    }
```

}

The output is always just one circle. How can I make it like a function call whenever I want to draw extra one circle it will just a simple call a function?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by "whenever I want to draw extra one circle it will just a simple call a function"?

Comment: Is `my.paint(null)` supposed to call `paint(Graphics g)`? Doesn't that give a NullPointerException then?

Comment: Hi Icedtrees, sorry for some vague message I have done. The meaning was i wish to create a function to generate circle with associate some text. So whenever my program needed to generate a new circle, i will just perform this function. End up in the JForm might generated several circles.

Comment: Hi Bram, the reason i did not pass Graphics g to paint function, because it doesn't need anything to pass in and since java.awt.Graphics is handling paint().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override paint() on a JFrame.

Custom painting is done by override paintComponent(...) on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame.

> it will draw me another circle.

There are two common approaches:

1. Keep a List of circles to draw
2. Draw the circles on a BufferedImage

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both approaches.

Comment: Hi camickr. appreciate for sharing. I had read the article you had posted. I'm new in Java. Still can't really how the code works fine. I had did change the paint to paint component but is not work at all now. Could you share me some hints on the coding?